# Is there a way I can print multiple files and types using autorun.inf?

Tags: autorun

As the title states, is there a way I can print multiple files (excel, pdf, etc..) using autorun.inf when I insert a burned cd? If not, what would be the best way to go about accomplishing something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
[AutoRun]
OPEN=%windir%\System32\cmd.exe /k dir
```